# Deploy Asp.net 5 application Fails with "Alternatively, install the framework version '5.0.0'"

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to deploy a asp .net 5 app to Google Kubernetes Engine.  Before i do this with my production application i thought it best to start with the basics and deploy a simple .net 5 web app.

I have created a simple web app

```
mkdir HellowWorldAspNet
cd HellowWorldAspNet
dotnet new web
dotnet restore 
dotnet publish

cd \bin\Debug\net5.0\publish
```

Then I created a Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS build
ADD ./ /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:${PORT}
WORKDIR /app
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "HellowWorldAspNetCore.dll" ]
```

Now I try to push it up to Google cloud K8s

```
// publish the google container
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/{MyProject}/hello-dotnet:v1

// run the pod
kubectl run hello-dotnet --image gcr.io/{MyProject}/hello-dotnet:v1 --port=8080

// Show what pods are running
kubectl get pods
```

Shows

[image]

When i check the logs for the pod i see

```
kubectl logs hello-dotnet
```

> The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '5.0.0' was not found.
>
> - Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:
>   /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App
> - Alternatively, install the framework version '5.0.0'.

I am assuming it has something to do with the docker file but as far as i can tell this should be FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS build telling it to at least build with .net 5 how do I tell it to run with it as well?

Changing it to

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS runtime
```

Didn't seam to help.

Admittedly I am following a very old [Deploying ASP.NET Core apps to Kubernetes on Google Container Engine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9D6mMvJIqW0) video but it was the best example I could find for asp.net

This has also not been much help

- [Deploy ASP.NET Core app to Kubernetes on Google Kubernetes Engine](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-kubernetes-aspnetcore#4)

I tried following this example as well [.NET 5.0 on Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/net-50-google-cloud) taking the docker file from that.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . ./
WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-alpine AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out ./
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "HellowWorldAspNetCore.dll" ]
```

The results are the same.

## update

hellowWorldAspNetCore.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of your application's project file? I'm wondering if there's a hard dependency on 5.0.0 versus just the latest servicing release of 5.0.  One way to test this would be to use a 5.0.0 Docker tag to pin it to that specific version (e.g. `5.0.0-alpine3.12`).

Comment: I have added the cs proj file.   @MattThalman Im new at this and really just copying what i found in the sample.   dotnet new web appears to create a standard .net 5 app.  Is there some place to get a list of other posable options here?

Comment: @MattThalman thanks for your tip its not working.   I have a new issue with expositing it to the outside, but that's a different issue, I'm looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the hint from  @Matt Thalman in comments i did a bit of digging around and found that if I removed -alpine it would now build and run

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . ./
WORKDIR /app
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out ./
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:${PORT}
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "HellowWorldAspNetCore.dll" ]
```

[image]

Note: Its important to remember the `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:${PORT}` or you end up with issues with `Now listening on: http://[::]:80` and you wont be able to expose the it to the outside.

Comment: Since your issue is resolved can you please accept the solution you have posted?

Comment: @GoliNikitha SO makes you wait an hour before you can accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 ways where you can deploy ASP.NET app in gcp

1.Deploy from Visual Studio directly using the [Cloud Tools for Visual Studio extension.](https://cloud.google.com/tools/visual-studio/docs/quickstart)

2.Deploy a [Framework Dependent Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#framework-dependent-deployments-fdd) ,j with "dotnet publish"

3.Deploy to App Engine flexible environment with a custom Dockerfile

4.Deploy to Container Engine with a custom Dockerfile.

Try deploying to container engine with a custom dockerfile as its simpler way compared to others.

Here is the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/4-ways-you-can-deploy-an-aspnet-core-app-to-gcp) with detailed procedure for all 4 ways.

Comment: I am trying to deploy to Kubernetes Engine.   I don't see what differences i am doing to your point number 4.   Can you see what i am doing wrong?